# Can't connect edges to each other

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

I'm trying to connect two edges of these meshes together, but every solution I try doesn't work. I'm using this for a game I'm working on, and the bricks I made need corner bricks so they can connect all the walls together.

[image: The problem]

Comment: do you mean that you're trying to do something like that? https://zupimages.net/up/23/13/bh0a.jpg

Comment: Is this one object with two separate meshes or two separate objects (looks like the latter)? You can only connect edges within the same object, so you need to join them with Ctrl+J. But be aware that they don't have separate origins and rotations anymore, the new object will inherit the data from the one that was marked as active (brighter outline when both are selected).

Comment: @moonboots yes that's my goal

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann It's 2 seperate objects I'm trying to join not like Ctrl + J. the top comment explains my goal

Comment: @rufu Yes, I guessed that you want to do something like in his comment, but no matter what the goal is - if you do not join the objects beforehand, you will not be able to make edge connections between their vertices. You could only create for example in object 1 duplicates of the vertices from object 2 that you want to connect and then make edges to those duplicates in object 1. But this will not connect object 1 with object 2.

Comment: You can probably use the Snap tool but please share your object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots Well, he said it's two separate objects but he does not want to join them with Ctrl+J. So even without the file I suspect that is one of the main problems.

Comment: Maybe he just want the brick to stick but keep them separate

Answer (score 2):

You could enable the *Snap to Vertex* option, select the 2 objects, switch to *Edit* mode, move the vertices on X or Y and snap them to the ones of the other object:

[image]

You could also use the *Shear* tool, the *Knife* tool, the Bisect tool...

Comment: i was going to join them later but if I need to Join, i will do so

Comment: It depends what you mean by "join"? You mean make one unique object with Ctrl J?

Comment: I am saying CTRL + J join

Comment: also, my object has like so many vertices the shear would take a lot of time https://imgur.com/a/YfZc4Qd

Comment: if even possible

Comment: My object has so many vertices as I said above, making 'shear' impossible practically. https://imgur.com/a/YfZc4Qd